# Why my mysqli_fetch_assoc is not working?

Tags: php

I want to return `$contact_id` but all I get is :

```
success.
the user id is
```

For example, in my insert.htm I enter $CheckContact : 
[image]

It should be returning : `the user id is 11`. This is my `user` table :

[image]

And if I click `checkcontact.php` again in my browser address bar then I get :

```
the user id is 23
```

It's always 23, no matter what `$CheckContact` is. 
Can you tell me what is wrong ? Here is my code :

```
<?php

require('dbConnect.php');

$CheckContact = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$CheckContact'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//if $CheckContact is in the user table...
if(isset($check)) {

    echo 'success.' . "<br>";

    // get the associated rows of $CheckContact
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    // get the associated user_id in that row

       $contact_id = $row["user_id"];
       echo "the user id is ", $contact_id;

} 
//if $CheckContact is NOT in the user table...
else {

    echo 'failure';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you switched on error reporting in PHP?

Comment: Can you share your form from insert.htm?

Comment: This Problem can occur, in a case when your query fails. `$check` would be null and it is passing the check of `isset` because it is set now. instead use `!empty`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe.

Comment: @FaizKhan insert.htm isn't the issue I am quite sure as I am getting success.

Answer (score 2):

When I change my code to :

```
<?php

require('dbConnect.php');

$CheckContact = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$CheckContact'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows >= 1) {

 etc....
```

It works ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
 why dont you use this:
<?php
$sql="Select query";
               $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                while($rws=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
to print all data
<?php 
}
?>
```

try empty() for $check this will indicate whether the variable contains null values or not